# Plugin crashes when loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects: is called

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbundle

I have been wanting to learn how to code on the OS X Platform and am giving it a go by learning how to make a custom color picker for the system provided color picker as it seems like a pretty simple concept.  I read some [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/DrawColor.pdf) on Apple's website to get me started, granted the code in their sample is old, but I was able to convert so it uses ARC and runs on 64 bit systems.

### My Implementation:

All custom color pickers must adopt the `NSColorPickingCustom` protocol, which I have done. I've created a Nib file called `Main` in which I've wired up the view to an IBOutlet property in the Principal Class. I've implemented the `- (NSView *)provideNewView:(BOOL)initialRequest` function as required by the protocol.  In this function, shown below, I've checked to see if a selector is available to determine which platform I am running on so that I know which `loadNibNamed` method I should invoke. I got this idea from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20844833/580724) posted on SO. Also, the deployment target for my project is set to 10.7.

```
- (NSView *)provideNewView:(BOOL)initialRequest {

    if(initialRequest) {
        if ([[NSBundle mainBundle] respondsToSelector:@selector(loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:)]) {
            // We're running on Mountain Lion or higher
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Main" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
        } else {
            // We're running on Lion
            [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Main" owner:self];
        }
    }

    return _view;

}
```

### Outcome:

When I start up the OS X color picker via an AppleScript I wrote, the color picker crashes with the following error that I pulled from the Console app (I still haven't figured out how to use the Xcode debugger with bundle projects):

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   abort() called

First 7 lines of the Application Specific Backtrace listed in the error report:

```
Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff861be25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8680be75 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8607f487 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 951
3   AppKit                              0x00007fff8787a44f -[NSColorPanel _provideNewViewFor:initialViewRequest:] + 91
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff8787a364 -[NSColorPanel setMode:] + 354
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff8787ce25 -[NSColorPanel _initWithPickers:] + 1157
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff878791fb -[NSColorPanel initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 792
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff87a37437 -[NSPanel init] + 98
```

### Additional Information:

If I keep the deployment target set to 10.7, and use the following function, the color picker application loads and shows my custom color picker:

```
- (NSView *)provideNewView:(BOOL)initialRequest {
    if(initialRequest) {
        [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Main" owner:self];
    }
    return _view;
}
```

If I keep the deployment target set to 10.9, and use the following function, the color picker application fails with the same error that I listed above:

```
- (NSView *)provideNewView:(BOOL)initialRequest {
    if(initialRequest) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Main" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
    }
    return _view;
}
```

I am hoping that someone can provide me with insight as to why the `loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects` method calls are failing, even though it is the method to use for the deprecated `loadNibNamed:owner:` method call. Ideally I would like to code my application to support both old and new systems, not just the latest which is why I would like for this to work the way I have implemented it in the function listed at the top of my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after doing some more research and trying to understand the issue my plugin was experiencing, another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126985/cocoa-loadnibnamedownertoplevelobjects-from-loaded-bundle) on SO helped shed some light on what is going on when a plugin calls the `loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects` method.

My understanding of the issue is that because I am creating a plugin, the code `[NSBundle mainBundle]` returns the bundle of the application, in this case, the OS X Color Picker Tool, in which a nib named `Main` does not exist. So instead, I need to get the bundle for my plugin, which can be fetched with the code `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]`.  After I implemented this, my plugin executed properly.  Listed below is my corrected code:

```
- (NSView*)provideNewView:(BOOL)initialRequest
{
    if( initialRequest) {
        NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
        if ([bundle respondsToSelector:@selector(loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:)]) {
            // We're running on Mountain Lion or higher
            [bundle loadNibNamed:@"Main" owner:self topLevelObjects:nil];
        } else {
            // We're running on Lion
            [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"Main" owner:self];
        }
    }
    return _view;
}
```